# Two conductor's in a magnetic field, canceling each other's EMF?

Tags: electromagnetism

If two conductor's are in a $\Delta$B, oriented the same in the field, and they induce equal $\epsilon$, can their wiring be oriented in a way that they can cancel each other's induced $\epsilon$?
So that that $\epsilon_t$= $\epsilon_1$ - $\epsilon_2$.

Similar to [twisted pair](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Twisted_pair) concept.